# How to Calculate GPA's in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

[image]

Ive just began learning MATLAB
I am in engineering school and we were given a problem to solve in matlab
the problem is as follows (also attached):

The text file called Transcript.txt lists the courses, grades and credits for a student transcript with comma-delimited data

Write a script that reads this data and does the following:

1. Computes the student's grade point average (GPA) for the courses listed. Note that the GPA is calculated by summing the product of the credits and grade for each course and then dividing this result by the total number of credits:

   Assign the result of this calculation to a variable named GPA.
2. Uses the GPA result to create a character array variable named GPAReport that contains for example 'The GPA is 3.25.' where the number  is replaced with the number computed from the given transcript and rounded to two decimal places.
3. Identifies the course in which the student earned their highest grade. Create a second character array variable named BestGrade that contains for example 'The student earned her best grade of 3.50 in MATH 123.'  Where the grade value and course number are retrieved from the given transcript data.  Note that there is only one instance of the highest grade in any of the tests.

I had no clue as to how to write this code so I tried this:

```
total_weighted_points = sum(grades .* credits);
total_credits = sum(credits);
GPA = total_weighted_points / total_credits;


GPAReport = sprintf('The GPA is %.2f.', GPA);


[max_grade, max_idx] = max(grades);
best_course = courses{max_idx};
BestGrade = sprintf('The student earned her best grade of %.2f in %s.', max_grade, best_course);


disp(GPAReport);
disp(BestGrade);
```

Comment: hard to help you without knowing the actual structure of the data in the .txt file. Try to post a screenshot or a modular piece of it so that your problem can be reproduced

Comment: Ive linked an image to the .txt file

Comment: @AbdullahLaher an image of text is the worst way you can share text data. You know what is the best way? as text......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something along these lines( may need some fixing) should work

```
%read file line by line
allLines=readlines('gpa.txt','EmptyLineRule','skip');

%initialize variables
sumGPA=0;
maxGrade=0;
sumCredits=0;



for ss=2:numel(allLines)
    %string extraction 
    courseLine=strsplit(allLines(ss),' ');
    currCourseName=courseLine{1};
    currCourseResults=strsplit(courseLine{2},',');
    currCourse=strcat(currCourseName," " ,currCourseResults{1});
    credits=str2double(currCourseResults{2});
    grade=str2double(currCourseResults{3});
    
    %sums
    sumGPA=sumGPA+credits*grade;
    sumCredits=sumCredits+credits;

    %max grade
    if grade>maxGrade
        maxGrade=grade;
        maxGradeCourse=currCourse;
    end

end

GPA=sumGPA/sumCredits;

fprintf('The gpa is %d\n',GPA);
fprintf('The best course is %s with a grade of %d\n',maxGradeCourse,maxGrade)
```

This is a baseline, it can be improved for sure in the middle section